# What happens if Billy Batson time travels?

Tags: dc, shazam

If Billy Batson time travels to the past or future and says "Shazam" will he still be transformed? I tried to Google the question and did not find an answer.

Comment: If Billy travels into his own past? Or if he just travels to a point before he was given his powers?

Comment: Let's say he has his powers and some how is transported through time either by mistake or on purpose as Billy.

Comment: In [Shazam! The Monster Society of Evil (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mind_and_the_Monster_Society_of_Evil#Shazam!_The_Monster_Society_of_Evil_(2007)) he went back to the Big Bang and his powers seemed to work just fine. Does that count?

Comment: I guess Valorium, with so many variations in the comics, TV shows and movies based on comic book superheros each medium is different in some ways.

Comment: I would think he would retain his powers, but I have no evidence for or against this.

Comment: Umm, any reason to think why he wouldn't retain his powers?

Comment: @Shreedhar Well, he does get them from an external source that might not recognize him as an authorized user.

Comment: @nick012000 but why is that? I'm just curious to know if its specified somewhere in the comics that there could be only one champion who can have the powers of the wizard. I don't think so.

Comment: @Shreedhar It's not that there might only be one champion at a time (there's multiple examples of multiple champions simultaneously), but that when he shouts out "Shazam" it's entirely possible that the wizard would look at him and go "Who are you? I don't know who you are, so I'm not going to give you my power."

Comment: @nick012000 I'm no scholar of the mythos, but the bits and pieces I've absorbed indicate the Wizard sitting in the Rock of Eternity very likely considers linear/sequential time to be a "quaint concept".

Answer (score 13):

The answer is "yes", his power still works.

The only instance where I can produce evidence for comes from the run of *Justice Society*, circa 2002.  In the story, Hawkwoman, Mr. Terrific, and Captain Marvel are all thrown deep into the past to ancient Egypt.  There they fight Vandal Savage and Ahk-Ton, perhaps the original Metamorpho born of the Orb of Ra.  Our Heroes find allies with a relatively newly-made Black Adam, the sorcerer Nabu, and the original Hawkman and Hawkwoman.

Trying to find help, Adam and Captain Marvel travel to the celestial realm.  There, they use the power of their transformation to hopefully attract the attention of the god Ra.

[image: Shazam in ancient Egypt]

[image: Shazam transforming back to Billy Batson]

As you say, there are so many re-re-reboots and variations of Captain Marvel/Shazam, I'm sure there more examples of the power working and others claiming it does not.